# Hide side-bar when a concrete page is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to hide a side-bar menu that I've implemented, but just in a concrete page, I'm using plain Javascript, but not succeed, now I'm gonna try it with Jquery. Anybody can give a tip or some doc. danke

Comment: post your code , how do want that we can help without it !

Comment: provide us with some code maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you side bar consists in one element which id is "sidebar".
In the page you want to hide, you link a .js page in which you write :

```
//Javascript 
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("sidebar").style.visibility = "hidden";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

.hide haha

you really need to upload some code so we can fix your prob.

Answer (score 0):

If the page has its own javascript attached to it, you could try something like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#side_bar_id').hide();
});
```

or if a general javascript file should handle it

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.split('/');
    if(path[0] == "concretepage") {
        $('#side_bar_id').hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').toggle(

function() {
    $('#B').css('left', '0')
}, function() {
    $('#B').css('left', '200px')
})
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#A, #B {
    position: absolute;
}
#A {
    top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background:orange;
}
#B {
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"><button>toggle</button></div>
```